# line-height difference between paragraphs and list items

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Paragraphs (`<p></p>`) and paragraphs in list items (`<li><p></p></li>`) have a different `line-height`.

**Example:** [answer with a paragraph and a list](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/203905/30863)

> [image: the paragraph and the list item have a different line-height]

- the paragraph has a calculated `font-size` of `14px` and a `line-height` of `19.6px`
- the list item has a calculated `font-size` of `14px` and a `line-height` of `16px`

I think it would be easier to read and look better if the list items get a higher (or even the same?) `line-height`.

Comment: I actually like it the way it is, with the tighter line height in lists. Lists really shouldn't be used for long-paragraphs (pretty sure I've broken this myself, but still), which explains the slightly tighter line height to 'group' them together

Comment: I think this is more a MetaSE question that Meta Arqade. Though I think it's a [tag:status-by-design] kind of question.

Comment: @M'vy: Other sites don’t have this issue. On Stack Overflow, the paragraphs in lists have the same line-height like paragraphs not in lists; on Software Recommendations the line-height is not identical, but list line-height is still higher (= easier to read) than on Arqade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pushed a fix for this. Change will go live after our next production build